# What's happen to my codes it appeared to be two exactly same intents?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments

I'm having one fragment and one fragmentActivity. In my fragment, I tried to intent the fragmentActivity. Whenever I intent back from fragment to fragmentActivity, I have two fragmentActivities. Maybe it recreate again the fragmentActivity whenever I use intent.

Initially main screen was 'HomeActivity' that hosts Fragment.

**Fragment**

```
intent = new Intent(getActivity(),ProcessActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_out);
```

**FragmentActivity**

```
intent = new Intent(ProcessActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_slide_in, R.anim.left_slide_out);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your fragment:

```
intent = new Intent(getActivity(),ProcessActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
   intent = new Intent(getActivity(),ProcessActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_out);
```

with

```
intent = new Intent(getActivity(),ProcessActivity.class);
getActivity.startActivity(intent);
getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_out);
```

thats it...